# Deferred binding failed error - Ginjector

Tags: gwt, guice

Hi I am having a problem with my gwt app, I am having the error below although I have this inherit:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.inject.Inject' />
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.mygwtapp.client.gin.Injector' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:98)
    at com.mygwtapp.client.Mygwtapp.onModuleLoad(Mygwtapp.java:29)
```

Mygwtapp.java

```
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {

    final Injector ginjector = GWT.create(Injector.class);

    final MainPresenter mainPresenter = ginjector.getMainPresenter();

    mainPresenter.bind();

    RootPanel.get().add(mainPresenter.getDisplay().asWidget());     

    logEvent(ginjector.getEventBus());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solution was to use GWT 2.1.0 M2 http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/detail?name=gwt-2.1.0.m2.zip&can=2&q=

Answer (score 2):

"deferred binding failed" errors are **always** preceeded by specific errors pointing at the exact problem.

Comment: the error was with the GWT library I used. Perhaps a mismatch with the guice library in the WEB-INF/lib folder. Cheers.