# Deferred binding failed

Tags: gwt, dependency-injection, guice, gwt-gin

My application is throwing:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.mygwtapp.client.gin.ClientAppGinjector' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
```

on this code inside the EntryPoint:

```
private final ClientAppGinjector injector = GWT.create(ClientAppGinjector.class);
```

What could be the problem?

**Here's the full error Log:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.mygwtapp.client.gin.ClientAppGinjector' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
    at com.mygwtapp.client.MainEntryPoint.<init>(MainEntryPoint.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:465)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:375)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Post the full error log, errors like this often have earlier roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ".gwt.xml" file, add the following line:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.inject.Inject"/>
```

Comment: I have this inherit on the gwt.xml

Comment: @xybrek: Sure, there can be several reasons (I think you had a similar problem a while ago already http://stackoverflow.com/q/6555062/291741 ;-) I suggest trying if your setup works with the official [GIN samples](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/source/browse/trunk/samples/) first. If not, then check the libraries (there is gin-1.5-post-gwt-2.2.jar and gin-1.5-pre-gwt-2.2.jar, make sure to use the right one).

Comment: Yah, but I need to use GWT 2.4.0, the Gin jars are from maven with version: 1.5.0

Comment: I'm not sure how I can know whether which gin-1.5 jar is being fetched from maven

Comment: incompatibility with the gwt version will give issues about an abstract class that should be an interface (or vice versa) - the full error log should show that. Is there no error before that RuntimeException?

Comment: I manually added gin-1.5-post-gwt-2.2.jar, now I'm getting this error: com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries) at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:503)

Comment: Without the rest of the exception (note the part that says 'see previous log entries') that is not a useful error message.

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same error message during runtime. When I tried "Google > GWT Compile" the stack trace helped me better. My problem was that the service interface used a class that wasn't **serializable**.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I resolved lom adding the following libraries:

- javax.inject.jar
- guice-assistedinject-3.0.jar
- aopalliance.jar

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. My getter method of Boolean object called `getBooleanObject()` instead of `isBooleanObject()`. Class `JsonEncoderDecoder` looked for method called `isBooleanObject()`, didn't find him, compilation failed. (gwt 2.8.0)